Trying to show shapefile in folium through javascript
I have a shapefile with postal codes in Belgium. In addition I have a distance-matrix from store-locations of one brand to all postal-codes. I managed to add markers to my map in PyQt5 QMainWindow using QWebEngineView. If in a ComboBox I select a different brand, different markers appear on the map. First the old ones are deleted, then the new ones are added. As "standard" Folium does not allow markers to be deleted, I do this through the html/ javascript in the html file and calling a javascript in my Python.
I wish to do the same for the shape consisting of a merged set of postal codes within a predefined reach of the markers.
As a Proxy, I created a simple shapefile circle_10km.shp that plots a circle around a coordinate in Belgium. If I use the "standard" way to show this on a folium map, it works perfectly:
    import geopandas as gpd
    import folium
    import os

    gdf = gpd.read_file('circle_10km.shp')
    center = [50.5, 4.5]  # Replace with your coordinates
    m = folium.Map(location=center, zoom_start=12)
    geojson_data = gdf.to_json()
    folium.GeoJson(gdf).add_to(m)
    m.save('map.html')  # Save the map as an HTML file

However, as I want to add and delete shapes from my map (as I successfully accomplished with markers), I wish to use a javascript to do this. Cleaned-up, it looks like:
        <script>
            var map = L.map('map').setView([50.8503, 4.3517], 8);
        
            L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            }).addTo(map).on('load', function() {
                });

            function addMarker(name, lat, lon) {
                L.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(map).bindPopup(name);
                return true; // Return a value indicating success
            }
            function addGeoJson(geoJsonData) {
                L.geoJSON(geoJsonData).addTo(map)
            }                    
        </script>

(the function addMarker works here fine like this).
From Python I then call the function like:
    def execute_js(self, script):
        print(f'Executing JS: {script}')  # Debugging statement
        self.map_view.page().runJavaScript(script, self.javascript_callback)

    def javascript_callback(self, result):
        print(f'JavaScript execution result: {result}')

    def load_shape_file(self):
        shapefile_path = 'circle_10km.shp'
        gdf = gpd.read_file(shapefile_path)
    
        geojson_data = gdf.to_json()
        geojson_data = json.loads(geojson_data)
        script = f"""
        console.log('Executing addGeoJsonToGroup');
        addGeoJson({geojson_data});
        """
        
        self.execute_js(script)

All works fine within Python, but nothing appears on the map.
I added some console debugging statements and map is loaded normally and correctly (adding a console statement in the function did not show anything, but did neither in the perfectly-working marker-function).
ChatGPT suggest the JSON data looks ok.

Your wording is confusing. What are you exactly trying to achieve ? Beware of the XY problem.

I wish the shapefile to appear on a map (with the html-code as shown in the question).

Then, why not simply use gpd.read_file("circle_10km.shp").explore().save("map.html") ?

As the circle_10km shape is already a debug-effort. The real problem is that I have a shapefile with Belgian postal codes. Based on certain criteria, I wish to merge a set of postal codes (resulting for example in a 10km radius circle) that I then want to show on the map. Then I want to change the parameters, resulting into different maps. Instead of redrawing the full map, I wish to be able to delete shapes later on. But first I need to get them on the map.

That would be an easy task but what still unclear to me is this : "..to delete shapes later on"". Do you mean that you need to check/uncheck the layer (i.e, toggling the visibility) of the shapes in each generated html/map ?

Yes. I have a Python application where I can select stores of a certain brand. If I select the brand (and select "plot locations") markers appear on the map. I can also delete those as I keep track of them.
Now I want to do the same with the postal code areas around the stores. I have a distance matrix defining which postal codes to include. But there is a tick-box to show or not show the "reach" of the stores. Also when I change the brand, new stores pop up and so new postal codes should not. "Standard" interaction between Folium and Python only adds and cannot delete (I think).

Are you referring to streamlit-folium ? In any case, your question's scope seems too broad, perhaps narrowing it down would help ;)

No I am not. Just a PyQt5 with a QWebEngineView.

Should I use streamlit-folium instead? Now I try to add and more important delete the markers through custom_htm that I inlude into the map

If you can (in your original post) describe the workflow (interaction of the user with the map(s)) and precise what are exactly the formats of the inputs, I can try proposing a solution with streamlit.

Thanks, I can try:

User chooses Brand from
self.group_combo = QComboBox()
User checks
self.show_locations = QCheckBox("Show locations")
self.show_reach = QCheckBox("Show reach")
in the first case markers appear on the map in the main window. If unchecked, they disappear again. The second marker should do the same with (calculated) shape files. There is a QSlider that determines the reach in km
how can I change my original post. Haven't found the edit-button yet


I think I've got the general idea. I'll try to add an answer once I'm at a laptop ;)

Appreciated. Still would hope to get the right java-scripting (however one should call it) done as well, but if streamlit is the answer, then all good as well :)

Would something like this (the general idea) gives you what you expect ? You still need to describe precisely the workflow and the inputs, though.

Great! This would be the general idea yes. In my case I have a check-box for the shapefile (the area) is displayed or not. the slider is not changed that often. And the area is based around the stores (so the red shapes when you select a brand in your model). Did you do this  with stream-lit ?

Great! This would be the general idea yes. In my case I have a check-box for the shapefile (the area) is displayed or not. the slider is not changed that often. And the area is based around the stores (so the red shapes when you select a brand in your model). Did you do this  with stream-lit ?
